# How to test PHP max_execution_time and default_socket_timeout with a simple PHP script?

Tags: php, fastcgi

I discovered that in php (on linux at least) the sleep(seconds); does NOT count toward timeouts!

So, my question is, what can I use "instead" of sleep(300); etc in a simple php script to test these timeouts?

(I'm trying to debug some php run via cgi/fastcgi, on php newer than 5.4 where safe mode was removed. Although deprecated setting's still present in our old php.ini, set to off.)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a `while(true) {}` loop. You can save the current `time()` before the loop & `break` after X seconds have passed if you want to wait less than 300 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Right after I posted question here, I looked into time etc and went with a time() + 30 > time etc...can post exact usage tomorrow (need get zzz now), but it seemed to work. I see now someone also posted a while true option.

Update:
To control "specific" amount of time, which is what I needed, this is what I ended up using minutes after posting this question and was working for me:

```
$curtime = time();
while ($curtime + 31 > time()) { }
echo "Testing timeouts and other errors."
```